# using powershell to pin an application shortcut on the Taskbar

Tags: powershell

My question is about the right use of PowerShell command about the way to pin an application shortcut on the Taskbar, my problem is as mentioned below:

If I execute this PowerShell line directly when prompted on PowerShell console:

```
(New-Object -com Shell.Application).NameSpace("directoryfile").ParseName("programname").InvokeVerb("taskbarpin")
```

that works perfectly, but I'm not able to do it when calling the PowerShell console from CMD prompt as below:

```
 c:>powershell -command "(New-Object -com Shell.Application).NameSpace("directoryfile").ParseName("programname").InvokeVerb("taskbarpin")"
```

I don't know why it's not working but if there is any error in that script please help me to solve it

Comment: `cmd.exe` can't parse quotes within quotes. Escape them with `\"`.

Comment: how can i modify it bacause i want to execute this command through .bat file

Comment: "i want to execute this command through .bat file" - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) already pointed out :
either escape the inner double quotes (so cmd doesn't interfere)

```
powershell -NonI -NoP -Command "(New-Object -com Shell.Application).NameSpace(\"directoryfile\").ParseName(\"programname\").InvokeVerb(\"taskbarpin\")"
```

or replace them with single ones:

```
powershell -NonI -NoP -Command "(New-Object -com Shell.Application).NameSpace('directoryfile').ParseName('programname').InvokeVerb('taskbarpin')"
```

Comment: As you are new to [SO] you might not know that the best way to acknowledge a good answer is to vote up and/or check mark as answer. See [why vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)